# Use Application owned Google Drive

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-drive-api

I need to build an application on **Google App Engine** with all the feature of **Drive SDK** with following Design Condition.

1. All the files should be available in a centralized Location/Drive of the application owned account
2. It should allow anonymous to upload and access files on the centralized Location/Drive.
3. The application should not prompt for any login or allow access Screen.
4. Drive must be capable to scale with respect to size

Please give me some inputs so that i can achieve this

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this?  Maybe your question is just a wee bit too broad.

https://www.google.co.jp/search?q=gae+sdk+google+drive&oq=gae+sdk+google+drive

Comment: I have implemented the drive service where it uploads file to the logged in google user drive. But i want to keep it as a centralized

Comment: You will need to use a Service Account. Here's a video which describes them well https://developers.google.com/events/8400075-3001/